# How to send Headers ('Authorization','Bearer token') in Mocha Test cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am writing a test case to test my API . When I try to test for any open API, it is working fine. But When I try to send Authorization Token along with my API, it is not working. Here is the code:

The way i am sending headers is:

`.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)`

Is it the correct way of sending?

I have tried to send the Authorization token in Auth. But not able to get the same. But when I tried to consume same in Postman, it is working fine.

```js
    it("Get some random Info", function(done) {
        chai
          .request(baseUrl)
          .get("/someRandomApi")
          .set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
          .end(function(err, res) {
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            done();
          });
      });
```

Comment: where the token is defined?

Comment: It is available globally , Even  i have tried by hard coding the token . I think there is no issue with token

Comment: Can you  please show your `baseUrl` variable

Comment: This is the base Url = "https://10.83.35.193"

Comment: @LeelaVathi it seems like your aren't specifying a port number. Try including the port number that your server is running on in the url. Also try including `http://` at the beginning on the url

Comment: Actually after checking same url in Postman , then i am using here . So url part is correct . I have checked it .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464230/how-to-test-an-express-rest-api-with-header-parameters-using-mocha-and-supertest

Comment: check this solution out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464230/how-to-test-an-express-rest-api-with-header-parameters-using-mocha-and-supertest

Answer (score 14):

I like to set up my tests in the following way:

```
let baseUrl = 'http://localhost:9090'
let token = 'some_authorization_token'
```

First I would instantiate my variables `baseUrl` and `token` at the very top of the test, right after `use()` part.

Next to come is the setup of the test.

```
    it("Get some random Info", function(done) {
       chai.request(baseUrl)
         .get('/someRandomApi')
         .set({ "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` })
         .then((res) => {
            expect(res).to.have.status(200)
            const body = res.body
            // console.log(body) - not really needed, but I include them as a comment
           done();
         }).catch((err) => done(err))
    });
```

Now, `.set()` doesn't necessarily have to be like mine, works in your case as well.

Comment: Only this one worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `auth` function to set the Authorization header.

```
it("Get some random Info", function(done) {
    chai
      .request(baseUrl)
      .get("/someRandomApi")
      .auth(token, { type: 'bearer' })
      .end(function(err, res) {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        done();
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

chai-http has `auth` function to send the Authorization Bearer token.

Accroding to chai-http code on [Github](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http/blob/601854fbf8ce0cf76603c6d8097563afa16a235a/dist/chai-http.js#L3359), token can be pass using:

`.auth(accessToken, { type: 'bearer' })`

The code would be like:

```
it("Get some random Info", function(done) {
   chai.request(baseUrl)
     .get('/someRandomApi')
     .set(token,{ type: 'bearer' }) //token is actual token data
     .then((res) => {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200)
       done();
     }).catch((err) => done(err))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `.get()` *after* you call `.set()`:

```js
it("Get some random Info", function(done) {
   chai
     .request(baseUrl)
     .set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token) //set the header first
     .get("/someRandomApi") //then get the data
     .end(function(err, res) {
       expect(res).to.have.status(200);
       done();
     });
});
```

Comment: @LeelaVathi what is that object you're passing into chai.request() ? It should be the server object. Like: chai.request(app) or it should be the localhost URL. Can you please include it in your code

Comment: Please find the url  i am passing a url . It is working without any Authorization , Means if i pass a url  like "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" , then it is working fine . But if i try to test an API which required to send Authorization and Bearer token , i am facing the above mentioned problem

Comment: the above throws an error. It worked just fine for me when it was `get` then `set` for the header.

Comment: it should always be after the request method i.e `set` should be called after `get`